# Get matching csv rows with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x

I got a question regarding Python in combination with CSV.

I want to check for specific id within in a specific column within a CSV file and find the results are connected to the input:

---

CSV:

[image: CSV FILE]

---

What i want to do is that when a user put as an input: ***b0074***, i want to return all the result: **b00ph, b11ph, b22ph, b33ph**

How can i do that within Python? Can anyone help me coding this? I got started with this:

```
with open('serials.csv') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to want to use the CSV module, you can use a list comprehension to filter rows from the CSV file. Below, items in column 0 (row[0]) are compared to your key value (b0074). If they match column 1 is added to the result of the list comprehension.

```
import csv

key = 'b0074'
with open('serials.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    result = [row[1].strip() for row in reader if row[0].strip() == key]

>>> result
['b00ph', 'b11ph', 'b22ph', 'b33ph']
```

This is equivalent to this "normal" for loop:

```
import csv

key = 'b0074'
result = []
with open('serials.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        if row[0].strip() == key:
            result.append(row[1].strip())

>>> result
['b00ph', 'b11ph', 'b22ph', 'b33ph']
```

Comment: Thanks! Awesome! This exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily achieved using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=' ', quotechar='|')
df[df['Row1'] == 'b0074']
```

Will filter the dataframe and return all rows where 'Row1' has that value